# Parsing different file types

Tags: java, kotlin, geojson

I am learning Kotlin and facing some difficulties understanding how I can proceed

Currently I have a **kml** file that gets sent from the front end but now I would like to accept **geoJson** and store this i database -> so I need to create a function in Kotlin to validate file type and based on type return the correct object.

This the function that accepts kml file and calls parseKmlToPolygons

```
fun parseKmlToPolygons(file: MultipartFile, applicationConfiguration: ApplicationConfiguration): Geometry {
    if (file.size > applicationConfiguration.getMaxKmlUploadFileSizeLimitInBytes()) {
        throw FileUploadSizeLimitReachedException()
    }
    return parseMultiParFileToPolygons(file.inputStream)
}

private fun parseKmlToPolygons(content: InputStream): Geometry {
    try {
        val kml = Kml.unmarshal(content) ?: throw InvalidKmlException("Failed to parse the kml file")

        return toGeometry(kml.feature)
    } catch (ex: IllegalArgumentException) {
        throw InvalidKmlException(ex.localizedMessage, ex)
    } catch (ex: InvalidGeometryException) {
        throw InvalidKmlException(ex.localizedMessage, ex)
    }
}
```

So I probably need to create a function that detects a correct file, but is it ok for me to return type Any here? Also, is it possible to get the type of the file from inputStream?

```
private fun detectFileType():Any {

}
```

My apologies if I am not really clear here, all I need is to replace the function that takes kml files to be able to take either kml or geoJson

Update

```
  //todo would be better to have detection logic separate 
private fun parseKmlToPolygons(file: MultipartFile): Geometry {
    val fileExtension: String = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.originalFilename)
    if (fileExtension == PolygonFileType.KML.name) {
        return parseKmlToPolygons(file.inputStream)
    } else if (fileExtension == PolygonFileType.GEOJSON.name) {
        return parseKmlToPolygons(file.inputStream)
    }
    throw FormatNotSupportedException("File format is not supported")
}
```

Comment: I'd rather user an enum class PolygonFileType { KML, GEOJSON } as return type of detectFileType(): PolygonFileType.

Comment: @HonzaMusil indeed to make it constant as it will never change, however, i need to detect file type , do you know an  efficient way to  locate file type from inputstream?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html contains originalFileName and contentType

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, what do you mean by the "file type"? Both types, geoJson and kml, are text files. They do not have any magic-number encoded defining the type. So, I see the following options:

- use extension of the original file uploaded by the user. For that you could use [MultipartFile.getOriginalFilename](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getOriginalFilename--)
- use content type set by the FE when uploading the file. [MultipartFile.getContentType](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getContentType--). Most likely it won't work out of the box and you will need to adjust your frontend.
- check actual file content. It's the most comlex option, but as the **kml** is xml-based and the **geoJson** is JSON-based it should be feasable.
- and finally the simplest solution: create separate endpoints for both types.

Comment: thank you , i am dealing with kml and geoJsoin for the first time including the langunage Kotlin itself so pardon me , from my understanding KML is similar to GeoJSON and can store points, lines, polygons, unlike GeoJSON, it's based on XML rather than JSON.  So since they both text files i wont be able to get mime type right as its the same so my option is to take the extension and detect it such way., if you have spear little time could you start chat and answer few questions

Comment: @Prozorov Sorry, I'm done for today. But if you decided to use file extension, it's pretty straight forward: get it from the `MultipartFile.getOriginalFilename` and either call `parseKmlToPolygons` or `parseGeoJsonToPolygons`.

Comment: thank you, i am trying to have a single function that based on detected file performs parsing

Comment: Hey man i have updated it with a detect method, would that do it or i can simplify or make it better somehow